# How is sortingPtr variable getting updated in the code below?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Need to understand how sortingPtr Variable is getting updated.

```
public class MergeSortedLinkedLists {

        public static Node mergeLinkedLists(Node head1, Node head2, Node mergedHead){
            Node sortingPtr = null;
            if(head1 == null && head2 != null){
                return head2;
            }
            if(head1 == null && head2 == null){
                return mergedHead;
            }
            while(head1 != null && head2 != null){
                System.out.println("head1.data - " + head1.data);
                System.out.println("head2.data - " + head2.data);
                System.out.println("sortingPtr - " + sortingPtr);
                /*while(sortingPtr != null){
                    System.out.print("sortingPtr.data - " + sortingPtr.data + " ");
                    sortingPtr = sortingPtr.next;
                }*/
                System.out.println();
                if(head1.data < head2.data){
                    System.out.println("head1 < head2");
                    if(mergedHead != null){
                        mergedHead.next = head1;
                        mergedHead = head1;
                    } else{
                        sortingPtr = head1;
                        mergedHead = head1;
                    }
                    head1 = head1.next;
                } else{
                    System.out.println("head2 < head1");
                    if(mergedHead != null){
                        mergedHead.next = head2;
                        mergedHead = head2;
                    } else{ 
                        sortingPtr = head2;
                        mergedHead = head2;
                    }
                    head2 = head2.next;
                }
            }

            if(head1 == null){
                mergedHead.next = head2;
            }
            if(head2 == null){
                mergedHead.next = head1;
            }
            return sortingPtr;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SinglyLinkedList linkedList1 = new SinglyLinkedList();
            linkedList1.head = linkedList1.new Node(10);
            linkedList1.head.next = linkedList1.new Node(50);
            linkedList1.head.next.next = linkedList1.new Node(70);
            linkedList1.head.next.next.next = linkedList1.new Node(90);
            linkedList1.head.next.next.next.next = linkedList1.new Node(100);

            SinglyLinkedList linkedList2 = new SinglyLinkedList();
            linkedList2.head = linkedList2.new Node(20);
            linkedList2.head.next = linkedList2.new Node(30);
            linkedList2.head.next.next = linkedList2.new Node(40);
            linkedList2.head.next.next.next = linkedList2.new Node(60);
            linkedList2.head.next.next.next.next = linkedList2.new Node(80);

            SinglyLinkedList mergedList = new SinglyLinkedList();
            mergedList.head = null;
            mergedList.head = mergeLinkedLists(linkedList1.head, linkedList2.head, mergedList.head);

            Node head = mergedList.head;
            while(head != null){
                System.out.print(head.data + " ");
                head = head.next;
            }
        }
    }

    class SinglyLinkedList{
        Node head;
        class Node{
            int data;
            Node next;

            Node(int data){
                this.data = data;
                next = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to merge 2 sorted linked lists. The method mergeLinkedLists is returning the head of the merged list in the sortingPtr variable. But I want to understand how the sortingPtr variable is getting updated to return the head of the merged list in the code mentioned above.

Comment: `sortingPtr = head1;` ?

Comment: But head1 will ultimately have values 90 and 100. sotringPtr will have merged list

Answer (score 0):

```
else{
                        sortingPtr = head1;
                        mergedHead = head1;
                    }
```

and

```
else{ 
                        sortingPtr = head2;
                        mergedHead = head2;
                    }
```

These block of codes ensure that when mergedHead is null(i.e. the merging process has not started) then we set the value of sortingPtr to the value of the mergedHead